# Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: Class 'List<dynamic>' has no instance method 'retainWhere' with matching arguments

Tags: android, flutter

I am trying to use 'retainWhere' to reduce the list to have only the matched values, but I am getting the error as [image]

```
static Future getSearchHistory() async {
    final value = await _storage.read(key: _keySearchHistory);

    return value == null ? null : json.decode(value);
  }

static Future setSearchHistory(history) async {
    var results = await getSearchHistory();

    
    print('results${results.runtimeType}');

    if (results != null) {
      var res = results.retainWhere(
          (result) =>
              result['value'].toLowerCase() ==
              history['value'].toString().toLowerCase(),
          orElse: () => null);
      if (results != null) {
        results.add(history);
        final value = json.encode(results);
        await _storage.write(key: _keySearchHistory, value: value);
      }
    } else {
      final value = json.encode(history);
      await _storage.write(key: _keySearchHistory, value: value);
    }
  }
```

Comment: Can you include your code and your error messages? Please don't use images for that.

Answer (score 0):

The function https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/List/retainWhere.html accepts no `orElse` argument. Change your code to:

```
static Future setSearchHistory(history) async {
    var results = await getSearchHistory();

    
    print('results${results.runtimeType}');

    if (results != null) {
      var res = results.retainWhere(
          (result) =>
              result['value'].toLowerCase() ==
              history['value'].toString().toLowerCase());
      if (results != null) {
        results.add(history);
        final value = json.encode(results);
        await _storage.write(key: _keySearchHistory, value: value);
      }
    } else {
      final value = json.encode(history);
      await _storage.write(key: _keySearchHistory, value: value);
    }
  }
```